Compute $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)-x+\frac{x^3}{6}}{x^5}$
Consider $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)-x+\frac{x^3}{6}}{x^5}$$
I want to evaluate this limit in three different ways.
First method - Hopital's Rule
The limit leads to indetermination $0/0$.
Consider $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\left[\sin(x)-x+\frac{x^3}{6}\right]'}{\left[x^5\right]'}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos(x)-1+\frac{x^2}{2}}{5x^4}=\frac{0}{0}$$
that it's still an indetermination. I apply Hopital's rule again:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\left[\cos(x)-1+\frac{x^2}{2}\right]'}{\left[5x^4\right]'}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-\sin(x)+x}{20x^3}=\frac{0}{0}$$
that it's still an indetermination. I apply Hopital's rule again:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\left[-\sin(x)+x\right]'}{\left[20x^3\right]'}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-\cos(x)+1}{60x^2}=\frac{1}{60}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}=\frac{1}{120}$$
Therefore, the initial limit is:
$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)-x+\frac{x^3}{6}}{x^5}=\frac{1}{120}$$

Second method - Taylor's expansion
Using that $\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}+o(x^6)$ for $x\to 0$, I can rewrite the initial limit as it follows:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)-x+\frac{x^3}{6}}{x^5}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}-x+\frac{x^3}{6}}{x^5}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{x^5}{120}}{x^5}=\frac{1}{120}$$

Any suggestions for a third method to solve this limit?

why you want a third method?

I wanted an additional method because both methods I used (which are the most standard obviously) involve the use of derivatives and I was wondering if this limit (and others like it) could be calculated using other ways

Using Taylor expansion is the standard and fastest method for this kind of limits. There's probably a method that does not involve derivatives, but I don't think it's relevant. You can take a look at this question

Any method is going to need to have some quantification of how sin(x) behaves relative to -x + x^3 / 6, for small x, which is determined by the behaviour of the derivatives of sin(x) near zero, which is precisely what the two methods are looking at.  (And anyway, in my view, l'Hopital is just implementing the consequence of writing two functions as Taylor series, so method 1 is method 2 in disguise).

Ok, I'm already happy with this two, finding a third method is actually quite useless.

The usual formal definition of $\sin$ is through the power series, so your second method doesn't use derivatives, just the definition of $\sin$ and basic results about power series and limits.

Using methods similar to those indicated here, assuming that limit $L$ exists
$$L=\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x-x+\frac{x^3}{6}}{x^5}\implies L=\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(2x)-2x+\frac{8x^3}{6}}{2^5x^5}$$
$$\implies 2^4L=\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\frac12\sin(2x)-x+\frac{2x^3}{3}}{x^5}\implies (2^4-1)L=\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\frac12\sin(2x)-\sin(x)+\frac{x^3}{2}}{x^5}$$
$$\implies (2^4-1)L=\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}\frac{\cos x-1+\frac x{\sin x}\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^4}=\frac18\implies L=\frac1{120}$$
indeed
$$\frac{\cos x-1+\frac x{\sin x}\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^4}=\frac{\cos x-1+\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^4}+\frac12\frac{\left(\frac x{\sin x}-1\right)}{x^2}\to \frac1{24}+\frac1{12}=\frac18 $$
where the second one comes from the well known $\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}\to \frac16$ and for the first one, assuming that limit $M$ exists
$$M=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos x-1+\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^4}\implies 2^4M=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos(2x)-1+2x^2}{x^4}$$
$$\implies 2^3M=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2-\sin^2x}{x^4} =\frac13 \implies M=\frac1{24}$$
indeed
$$\frac{x^2-\sin^2x}{x^4}=\frac{x+\sin x}{x}\frac{x-\sin x}{x^2}\to 2 \cdot \frac16=\frac13$$

COMMENT.-(This is not an answer!) The difficulty in finding a third method for your problem is that your statement uses a partial series expansion of $\sin(x)$ in the numerator and the corresponding power of $x$ as the denominator. This forces things in such a way that it becomes very difficult (or perhaps impossible) to find the third method you want. The problem might grow in difficulty (only for L'Hôpital's rule) but your two ways of finding the solution would still be efficient.
So we can enunciate: Find the limit when $x\to0$ of
$$\frac{\sin(x)-x+\frac{x^3}{6}-\frac{x^5}{5!}+\frac{x^7}{7!}}{x^9}$$ which clearly is equal to $\dfrac{1}{9!}$ before calculation.

You can check that
$$\sin(x) - x + \frac{x^3}{6} = \frac{1}{24} \int_0^x (x-t)^4 \cos t \, dt.$$
Now, if $0 < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$, then $\cos x \le \cos t \le 1$ for $t \in [0, x]$.  Therefore,
$$\frac{1}{24} \int_0^x (x-t)^4 \cos x \, dt \le \sin(x) - x + \frac{x^3}{6} \le \frac{1}{24} \int_0^x (x-t)^4 \, dt,$$
or in other words,
$$\frac{1}{120} x^5 \cos x \le \sin(x) - x + \frac{x^3}{6} \le \frac{1}{120} x^5.$$
Applying the squeeze theorem, we thus get $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\sin(x) - x + \frac{x^3}{6}}{x^5} = \frac{1}{120}$.  Since the function $\frac{\sin(x) - x + \frac{x^3}{6}}{x^5}$ is even on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \}$, that implies that in fact $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x) - x + \frac{x^3}{6}}{x^5} = \frac{1}{120}$.
(Of course, you could view this as cheating since it's just extracting an important part of a certain proof of Taylor's theorem, in the form of an integral expression for the remainder term.)
